# Moment JS ("Must to show days in next week")

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, momentjs

I'm working on a weather service and I need to write a code for showing the weather forecast for next week. From the server, I only have a "time" entity with "value" of next Monday like  "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000+02:00".

```
{
    "message": "Show me the weather for next week",
    "entities": [
        {
            "value": "weather",
            "text": "weather",
            "entity": "radio_tag"
        },
        {
            "value": "play_next",
            "text": "next",
            "entity": "media_control"
        },
        {
            "value": "next",
            "text": "next",
            "entity": "next"
        },
        {
            "value": {
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000+02:00",
                        "grain": "week",
                        "type": "value"
                    }
                ],
                "value": "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000+02:00",
                "grain": "week",
                "type": "value"
            },
            "entity": "time"
        },
        {
            "value": "weather_condition",
            "entity": "sub_intent"
        }
    ],
    "intent": "weather_condition",
    "user_id": "5258",
    "language_id": "56",
    "driver": "gigaaa",
    "abort": "0",
    "extras": {
        "coordinates": {
            "lat": "44.4150804",
            "lng": "19.1290729"
        }
    },
    "conversation_messages_count": "1"
}
```

For example, if today is Tuesday, I must show Monday and Tuesday for next week, if today is Saturday (04.04), I must show every day from Monday (06.04) to Saturday(11.04) for next week. I am a beginner and I must use Moment JS for this.

I tried this condition  `if (this.conversation.payload.grain === 'week' && moment().startOf('isoWeek').isSame(this.conversation.payload.forecastTime))` 
but the second part of condition is not correct.

Comment: Your requirements don't really make a lot of sense: why if it's a Tuesday, you only return Monday + Tuesday next week, but when if it's a Saturday, you want the entire week ahead?

Comment: The API we use supports display for up to 7 days. So I said if today is Friday, we have 2 days left by the end of this week. Therefore, in the next week it will show another 5 days, that is, from Monday to Friday. I do not need to show days this week, only days in the next week. Understand?

Comment: Still, that doesn't explain your logic of wanting to display Monday and Tuesday of next week ONLY if today is Tuesday.

Comment: See. For example, if today is Tuesday (31.03), the next 7 days are: (01.04), (02.04), (03.04), (04.04), (05.04), (06.04), (07.04).
Since (06.04), (07.04) is next week, I only need to show them. Do you understand me now?

Answer (score 1):

We take the current date and check if we aren't in the same isoweek as the data in order to filter out data rows from the current week. We then take the current date and add a week so we can check that <1 week has passed.
Theoretically, as long as the timezone of the user and the returned data are the same, it should be what you need.

```
var valueFromData = this.conversation.payload.value;
var dateFromData = moment(valueFromData).startOf('day');
var oneWeek = moment().add(7,'d').startOf('day');
if(moment().startOf('isoweek').isBefore(dateFromData)
   && dateFromData.isBefore(oneWeek))
```

Comment: But I can't hardcode this "moment('2020-04-10T00:00:00.000+02:00')". What happens in two or three weeks? Understand me?

Comment: So, you'd use the variable from your data: `this.conversation.payload.value`. The rest is based on the current time.